# What tape is appropriate for underlayment?

Tags: flooring, underlayment

I am installing bamboo flooring with Floormuffler underlayment. This type includes a moisture lip & adhesive for joining the long sides.

I have a few seams to join that don’t have the lip/adhesive, and a couple small tears to repair.

The manufacturer simply states:

> tape the seams together with 2” tape that meets the moisture vapor transmission rate for this type of installation.

Is there a more general purpose tape that is effective as underlayment tape?

Answer (score 0):

Tuck tape is a good choice.  It is used for moisture barriers like poly.

[https://www.amazon.com/Tuck-Tape-Construction-Grade-Sheathing/dp/B01N6L7FK0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N6L7FK0)